# Ответ php через json

Tags: jquery, json, php, javascript

Есть форма с кнопкой, требуется отправить запрос и получить ответ json от php скрипта:

```
echo json_encode( array( 'load' => 'Обновлено' ) );

<form id="parse" method="post" action="/admin/parse">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Обновить картинки для карусели" />
</form>

<div id="results"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#parse').submit(function(e){
        //отменяем стандартное действие при отправке формы
        e.preventDefault();
        //берем из формы метод передачи данных
        var m_method=$(this).attr('method');
        //получаем адрес скрипта на сервере, куда нужно отправить форму
        var m_action=$(this).attr('action');
        //получаем данные, введенные пользователем в формате input1=value1&input2=value2...,
        //то есть в стандартном формате передачи данных формы
        var m_data=$(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: m_method,
            url: m_action,
            data: m_data,
            dataType: "json",       
            success: function(result){ 
                $('#results').html(alert(result.load));                
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

запрос успешен, а json не выводит сообщение, хотя сервер возвращает json массив. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или добавьте константу "JSON_FORCE_OBJECT" в json_encode():

```
echo json_encode( array( 'load' => 'Обновлено' ), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
```

Или без изменений, но обращайтесь, как к массиву, а не объекту:

```
$('#results').html( alert(result['load']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#results').html(result.load); не?

Comment: в первую очередь пробовал, потом решил через алерт попробовать вывести

Comment: вообще решений нет?

Answer (score 0):

У тебя функция поскакала быстрее чем ответ пришел

```
success: function(result){ 
if (result.load) {
     $('#results').html(alert(result.load));                
 }
}
```